# Android: Dealing with CheckBox in a ListView

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-listview

I'm using a `SimpleAdapter` to fill my `ListView` with below code.

```
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,
            saleDriver.getOutstandings(clientId),
            R.layout.outstanding_list_row, new String[] { "sale_id",
                    "sale_date", "invoice_number", "sale_total", },
            new int[] { R.id.tt_check_box, R.id.tt_invoice_date,
                    R.id.tt_invoice_no, R.id.tt_invoice_tot });

    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

According to above code, i have bind `sale_id` with `CheckBox (R.id.tt_check_box)` in the `listview`. When i run the program, value of `checkboxes` displayed right of the CheckBox as text. but i don't want to display them.

My actual need is, when user checked `checkboxes`, i need to get `sale_id`s bind with them.

How could i access `sale_id`s bind with checked `checkboxes` in my java programe ?

Comment: [check this library](http://androidcustomviews.com/portfolio/multichoiceadapter/) may be it help you.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice
```

Comment: when using `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice`, my list view color changed to white. texts in list view doesn't displayed.

Comment: i have replaced `R.layout.outstanding_list_row` in above code with `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice`

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listadvanced_interactive Please go through this link.

Answer (score 0):

Override the getView() function in the SimpleAdapter and use the value of sale_id to check/uncheck the checkbox. Then use this custom adapter for your list.

EDIT:
In looking at another answer, my refined guess is that you need the Multiple Choice solution rather than this (since you need to find out the selections). This solution is more to display the checkbox based on existing data. If you still need this, let me know and I will post the sample code once I have access to my code.

Comment: can u provide some example ?

Comment: when using `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice` in Multiple Choice solution, my list view color changed to white. texts in list view doesn't displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I've attached code to obtain listview that works with multichoice checkboxes..

```
public class MultiChoiceActivity extends Activity {
```

String[] choice = { "Choice A", 
   "Choice B", "Choice C", "Choice D", "Choice E"};

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    choiceList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter
    = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
      android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, 
      choice);
    choiceList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    choiceList.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

[Refernce Link](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/09/multi-choice-listview.html)